# solve $y^{(4)}+y=0$ ,$y(0)=0,y'(0)=0,y''(0)=-1,y'''(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

here is my answer but the answer of the textbook is $\frac{-2}{3}e^x-\frac{1}{10}e^{2x}-\frac{1}{6}e^{-2x}-\frac{16}{15}e^{-\frac{X}{\sqrt{2}}}$
and it is very different from my answer.What is the problem of my answer?

Comment: The provided answer is definitely wrong. Are you sure you didn't look at the wrong question/answer?

Comment: yes, and also there is not such a long answer like this in solutions part

Comment: So it is problem of the book and I go for calculate constants? I think it is also long way to find constants Isnt it?

Comment: Your approach is correct, but note that there is only one $C$ per $r$ value, not two. Combining conjugates together gives$$y=C_1e^{x/\sqrt2}\cos(x/\sqrt2)+C_2e^{x/\sqrt2}\sin(x/\sqrt2)+C_3e^{-x/\sqrt2}\cos(x/\sqrt2)+C_4e^{-x/\sqrt2}\sin(x/\sqrt2)$$

Comment: Oh Thanks We do this because $sin(-t)=-sin(t),cos(-t)=cos(t)$ right?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

$$y^{(4)}+y=0$$
$$r^4+1=0 \quad\implies\quad r=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(\pm 1 \pm i)$$
$$y(x)=a\:e^{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+i)x}+b\:e^{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(-1+i)x}+c\:e^{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1-i)x}+d\:e^{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(-1-i)x}$$
With conditions at $x=0$ :
$$\begin{cases}
y(0)=0=a+b+c+d\\
y'(0)=0=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+i)a+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(-1+i)b+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1-i)c+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(-1-i)d\\
y''(0)=-1=(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+i))^2a+(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(-1+i))^2b+(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1-i))^2c+(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(-1-i))^2d\\
y'''(0)=0=(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+i))^3a+(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(-1+i))^3b+(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1-i))^3c+(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(-1-i))^3d 
\end{cases}$$
This system of four linear equations is easy to solve for $a,b,c,d$ observing simplifications such as $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+i))^2=i$ and many others. The result is :
$$a=d=\frac14 i \quad;\quad b=c=-\frac14 i$$
$$y(x)=\frac14 i\:e^{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+i)x}-\frac14 i\:e^{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(-1+i)x}-\frac14 i\:e^{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1-i)x}+\frac14 i\:e^{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(-1-i)x}$$
Or with sinusoidal functions such as $e^{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+i)x}=e^{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}x}(\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}x\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}x\right)$ and simplification :
$$\boxed{y(x)=-\frac12 e^{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}x}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}x\right)+\frac12 e^{-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}x}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}x\right)}$$